# How should I know the sentence 'Have all alike become extinguished'?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

In this following context, how should I understand the clause 'Have all alike become extinguished'?

Should I take it as: 'all alike have become extinguished'?

Context:

> The life-groups that have passed away,
>
> At death as well as during life,
>
> Have all alike become extinguished,
>
> And never will they rise again.

Source: P. 54

Fundamentals of Buddhism

By Nyanatiloka mahathera

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about unusual (poetic?) phrasing in a *translated* text

Comment: In English-language poetry, there is a common practice to capitalize lines. The capitalization does not mark the start of a sentence. You have to use other clues, including knowledge of grammar, and understanding of the meaning, to work out the division into sentences.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it means "They have all equally become extinguished."

**they have all** and **they all have** are both acceptable word orders in English.

Overall, the choice of the words and the word order are very poetic, and this may also not have been written by a native speaker, so I would not regard it as a very good model to emulate.

Comment: I think your linked NGram chart might be misleading, because the rise of ***they all have*** is probably mostly things like *...all have **ten fingers and ten toes***, whereas the actual usage under consideration concerns [***they have been all***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+have+all+been%2Cthey+all+have+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) as opposed to the far more natural ***they have all been***. Or ***they all have been***, or whatever

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a good point.  On further examination, I don't see such a clear pattern, so I'm going to remove the Ngrams link.

Comment: OP's cited ***Have all alike become extinguished*** is certainly "valid", but I can't make up my mind whether it's archaic, poetic, or just "clumsy" (or perm any 2 from 3! :) I think the natural phrasing is just ***Have all been extinguished*** (where I suppose ***alike*** is some kind of "poetic intensifier", but it doesn't really work for me). Maybe I'd go for *Have been extinguished, **every one***, but I'd rather just forget about intensifying the text anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The subject of "have become" is "life-groups". The sentence reads like this:

> The life-groups ... have all alike become extinguished ..."

The meaning of the original is that all those things (life-groups) have *similarly* become extinguished.

Your rephrasing "all alike have become extinguished" does not mean the same thing. Your version means either that all things that are similar to those life-groups have become extinguished OR that all (of something?) have become extinguished in a similar way to life-groups. In either case, "life-groups" is not the subject of "have become".